# How to retain an android app imageButton's onClick state after restarting, pressing back and changinging orientation

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that control light bulb remotely.
so i require that app saves automatically the previous state(variables, onlick button, etc) and resume it after i restart the app.
For example if i pressed on bulb(in my code it changes picture on click) and picture changes so when i close app and reopen it, the image shown should be changed one.

Here's my code

```
package room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton ib;
MediaPlayer toggleSound;
ImageButton aButton,aButton2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toggleSound=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.z);
    aButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    aButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean c = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked", false);
    Boolean d = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked2",false);

    if(c) {
        aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }
    else {
        aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);

    }
    if(d){

        aButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
    }
    else {

        aButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
    }
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


public void buttonClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean c = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked",false);
    if (!c) {
        aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
        toggleSound.start();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("clicked", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    if(c){
        aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("clicked", false);
        editor.commit();
        toggleSound.start();

    }
}
public void buttonClick2(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean d = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked",false);
    if (!d) {
        aButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
        toggleSound.start();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("clicked2", true);
        editor.commit();
    }
    if(d){
        aButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("clicked2", false);
        editor.commit();
        toggleSound.start();

    }
}
```

And here's the XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="room.bt4u.com.roomcontrol.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ROOM NO. 1046"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#0786e7"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:src="@drawable/off"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#01FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:src="@drawable/off"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#01FFFFFF"
    android:onClick="buttonClick2"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Swarnveer&apos;s"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#f20606"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Sajal&apos;s"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"

    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#f20606"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when you press it manually save some boolean in sharedpref and when you recreate or change orientation then check that boolean and set values accordingly

Comment: when i press bulb(white) it becomes yellow
so if my app gets killed or orientation changes i want the bulb to show yellow automatically without any click

Comment: by default it is white or yellow ?

Comment: default image is white and when clicked changes to yellow bulb image

Comment: so it will show default value to change it save any value after state change and when you come back in activity check value and set value

Comment: i am new to android can you please elaborate how can i do that by checking my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: ok i am sending you code only for buttonClick1 rest do by your self

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: Welcome code answered plz check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Try this:


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toggleSound= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.z);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Boolean c = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked");
            if(c){
                aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
            }
            else {
                aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
            }        
        }


        public void buttonClick(View v) {
            switch (choose){
                case 1:ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton) v;
                    aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                    toggleSound.start();
                    choose++;
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("clicked", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    break;
                case 2:ImageButton bButton = (ImageButton) v;
                    bButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("clicked", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    toggleSound.start();
                    choose--;
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: remove getActvity. i was working on fragment. in activity no need getActivity

Comment: i declare ImageButton aButton; globally

Comment: also in getBoolean("STRING",false)
there should be a true or false
it was showing errow so i put default false

Comment: aButton = findViewById(R.id.YOUBUTTONID) ; paste YOUBUTTONID and put this line below setContentView

Comment: default false is ok. it should be there.

Comment: app is not crashing not crashing now but it's not functioning ..

default state now is on(yellow)
when clicked state is same ON
when clicked another time goes OFF

And when restarting app default is showing ON everytime

Comment: thats because of you variable choose check your logic

Comment: my logic is fine as choose=1
if choose=1, and i click>becomes yellow>choose++
now if clicked choose becomes 2(due to choose++)>sets white>choose--

Comment: Now its retaining it's state but if i close it when it is yellow(ON) then next time when i restart it shows yellow(that is ok) but i click to get white(off), it doesn't change with one click
i have to press two times

Comment: used same method for button2
but don't know why it's totally depending upon button 1

Comment: done..editted the code
Buttonclick is working fine but buttonclick2 not with same logic

Comment: public void buttonClick2(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean d = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("clicked",false);
...
}
using clicked in use clicked2 instead

Comment: aah such a silly mistake i did...thanks for supporting that much. you made my day

Comment: if you can help me on this another question [LINK]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772102/usage-of-gif-in-imagebutton?noredirect=1#comment59215863_35772102

 that would be great

Answer (score 1):

*You can use SharedPreferences:*

referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for the infos:
You can use `SharedPreferences` to save little setting datas on your phone.

In your `onPause()`, use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("myKey", "myColorState").apply();
```

In this way the setting of "myColorState" is saved under the key "myKey".

In `onResume()` you can retrieve this value using

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String myColor = prefs.getString("myKey", "defaultValue");
```

In this way you have your datas and you can use them in the activity

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have bidirectional communication with the Bulb, saving the states to `SharedPreferences` seems like the best way to go.

You can retrieve the data from the `SharedPreferences` in your `Activity` or `Fragment` lifecycle Methods (`onConfigurationChanged()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()`).

[Check out SharedPreferences here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use SharedPref for saving your data using any key on screen orientation change or on backpress and you can again get that data using this key also.

Comment: when i press bulb(white) it becomes yellow so if my app gets killed or orientation changes i want the bulb to show yellow automatically without any click